# For bankruptcy, are your finances taken into account at the time of filing, or at the time of the 341 meeting several months later?

Tags: united-states, bankruptcy

Pretty much just the title. Just wondering if finances taken into account are at the time of filing or at the time of the [341 creditors meeting?](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/11/341)

Asking as a matter of law - what does the law say?

Comment: For what purpose within the bankruptcy? There isn't necessarily a single data upon which this is evaluated for all purposes.

Comment: In particular, the rules are different between Chapter 7 and Chapters 11, 12 and 13.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of filing it is typical to file a long form with information about the state of your finances. Weeks or months later at the time of meetings or hearings, it is plausible that someone might ask for updated information, but I think that is unusual. Generally if you have a negative change in finances it might be worthwhile to file an update, and if there is a positive change in finances it might be worthwhile to delay it until the plan is finalized, or at the very least avoid making that information known more than necessary. For example, no tweeting about your big inheritance, and no flashy purchases from your lottery win.

Comment: "Weeks or months later at the time of meetings or hearings, it is plausible that someone might ask for updated information, but I think that is unusual." It is actually routine to ask for updated information.

Comment: @ohwilleke a routine answer would be akin to "outstanding debt has increased by the relevant fees."